# telnet connection to multiple hosts and ports

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, telnet

i need an example script or bat file where by i want to do the following :>

test the telnet connection and ports to 3 different machines and ports at the same time.

the machine is very locked down, so unable to install putty or any other 3rd party apps or have web access.

I just need the script to telnet to the 1st box and then move to the next.

i have tried the script below but it just stops on the 1st box

```
<job>
<script language="VBScript">
    Option Explicit
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim WshShell
    set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "telnet x.x.x.x 7005"
    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
    WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
    WshShell.SendKeys "telnet x.x.x.x 8600"
    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
    WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
    WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
    WScript.Quit 
</script>
</job>
```

hope someone can shed some light on this.

Many thanks

Marzanur

Comment: If you manually try to run the `telnet` command to connect, is the output what you expect? Can you really run commands like `exit` at once? There's no login prompt that holds you up?

Comment: I just want to do a simple telnet connection test to the boxes without having to login. It more for checking network connectivity.

Comment: I thought the exit command would have stopped the current session and moved onto the next. Apologies, as i am not a programmer, so all these commands etc are still very new to me

Comment: If it is for testing network connectivity , then why not use ping?

Comment: i need to check to make sure those ports are open, hence using telnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet x.x.x.x 7005"
WshShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"
WshShell.SendKeys "^]"
WshShell.SendKeys "quit{Enter}"
```

CTRL + ] jumps out of your telnet session and to the terminal console where you can type quit.

Comment: Guys thank you all so much for the suggestions.. i will give it a try and will let you all know how it works out..again thank you

Comment: <job>
    <script language="VBScript">
    Option Explicit
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim WshShell
    set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    'Telnet Script to connect to IP and Ports for Connectivity Checks
    'Step 1 - Telnet to x.x.x.x 7005'
    WshShell.SendKeys "telnet x.x.x.x 7005"
    WshShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"
    WScript.Sleep 10000
    WshShell.SendKeys "^]"
    WshShell.SendKeys "quit{Enter}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    THEN THE NXT TELNET
    WScript.Quit 
     </script>
     </job>

Comment: You can click the up arrow on helpful suggestions and the accept button for the suggestion that worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this script:

You need to seperatate the

```
 Telnet *.*.*.* 7005
```

Commands with

```
 wscript.sleep 1000
```

So that the computer has time to connect. Secondly. Telnet opens in a unique command line interface and "exit" is not an accepted by the telnet interface. However, "quit" is used.

So to replace:

```
 Wshshell.sendkeys "exit"
```

With

```
 Wshshell.sendkeys "quit"
 'Wait for close
 Wscript.sleep 500
```

Telnet commands ->  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c.aspx